# Expected symbol before '=' token

Tags: c, syntax-error

i am making a tic tac toe game in C and I have some problems with the code.

player.h:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
#define PLAYER_H_INCLUDED

#include "gameLib.h"

struct Player
{
    int score = 0;
    char name[15];
    char symbol;
    int status;
};
void incraseScore(struct* Player p);
void changeName(struct* Player p, char newName[]);
void changeStatus(struct* Player p, int status);
void writeSymbol(struct* Player p, int locaton);

#endif // PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
```

player.c:

```
#include <player.h>

void incraseScore(struct* Player p)
{
    p->score += 1;
}

void changeName(struct* Player p, char newName[])
{
    p->name[] = newName[];
}

void changeStatus(struct* Player p, int status)
{
    p->status = status;
}

void writeSymbol(struct* Player p, int locaton)
{
    int i, j;
    extern char table[3][3];

    for (i=0; i<3; ++i){
        for (j=0; j<3; ++j){
            if (table[i][j] != 'X' && table[i][j] != 'O'){
                if (table[i][j] == 3*i+j+1){
                    table[i][j] = p->symbol;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gameLib.h:

```
#ifndef GAMELIB_H_INCLUDED
#define GAMELIB_H_INCLUDED

char table[3][3];

#endif // GAMELIB_H_INCLUDED
```

main.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_INCLUDED
#define MAIN_H_INCLUDED

#include "player.h"
#include "gameLib.h"

#endif // MAIN_H_INCLUDED
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

in player.h i receive 5 errors:

```
on line 8: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token
and on lines 13, 14, 15, 16: expected '{' before '*'
```

I don't understand why i receive this. I am beginner on structures and headers, so take me slow. Who can explain me those errors and correct me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems,

First, although initialization of non-static data members is legal C++, it isn't allowed in C:

```
struct Player
{
    int score = 0; // ERROR in C
    ....
};
```

Second, this is syntactically invalid:

```
void incraseScore(struct* Player p);
//                      ^ this has no place here
```

You need

```
void incraseScore(struct Player* p);
```

Comment: yep.... thanks! about pointer to structure utilization, I saw this somewhere on a site and I thought this is correct;